# How to migrate data from Table 1 to table 2 using php

Tags: mysqli

I want to migrate Data from table 1 to table 2

the same tables have the same field_names and structure

I used this query:

```
$sql1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table_1`");
while($data = $sql2->fetch_object()){
    $sql2 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table_2 ('field_1','field_2','field_3') VALUES('$data->value_1','$data->value_2','$data->value_3')");
}
```

Table_1 have 3000 records 
the problem here is the query insert only 700 records and it gives me this error message:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp\htdocs\assadara-group.com\t2t.php on line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following line in the start of your php code
     ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

You can change zero (mean unlimited time execution)  to any number in seconds (300 = 5 minutes)

For more info. PHP manual
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php